# OnActivityResult not being called from child activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a child activity that starts off like this in the class:

```
public class CaptureSignature extends Activity {
 .....
}
```

It's in the manifest as an activity, and is started from an ActionBarActivity's button like so:

```
 public void captureSignatureRef(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CaptureSignature.class);
    intent.putExtra("Source", "Ref");
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
}
```

When I'm done with CaptureSignature, I press this button to send back a result to the parent Activity:

```
 mDone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.putExtra("Source", Source);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

It gets called on debug, and works without a problem. But my parent activity's function is never called, no debug on the method, no nothing:

```
 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        String source = data.getStringExtra("Source");
        //do something here


    }

}
```

I tried changing the child activity to a ActionBarActivity, but it crashes on the emulator with no explanation or complaint when it's initaiated. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29

*requestCode    If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.*

In your code you are passing RESULT_OK, which is -1.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);
```

To fix this issue replace it with some positive integer value.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that I see is that you have to send your own `Activity` identifier when starting `Activity`

```
public static int CHILD_ACTIVITY = 123;

public void captureSignatureRef(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, CaptureSignature.class);
    intent.putExtra("Source", "Ref");
    startActivityForResult(intent, CHILD_ACTIVITY);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method signature for `startActivityForResult`:

`public void startActivityForResult (Intent intent, int requestCode)`

`requestCode`: If >= 0, this code will be returned in onActivityResult() when the activity exits.

Since you are passing in `RESULT_OK`, which equals -1, you don't get a callback.